# Loop through files in _posts subfolder - Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid, templating

I am using Prose.io as my CMS for github. In which I have set the root directory to /_posts. In /_posts I have made a folder "staticpages", this contains some markdown files with text. Can I loop through these files? I can't seem to figure out how.

So my file tree looks like:

```
root
   |
   _posts/
      |
      staticpages/
         |
         myfile.md
```

And I want to:

```
{% for pages in posts.staticpages %} {{ page.title }} {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Have a look at the defaults. You can assign a special variable to the yaml header
{% assign posts = site.posts | where:VAR, VALUE %}
and then loop over "posts".
For frontmatter defaults in jekyll see:
http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#front-matter-defaults

Comment: So, I can give them a default category per folder and then loop trough the posts and only include those with a specific category ?

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:
In your `_config.yml` you specify

```
defaults:
  - scope:
      path: "_posts/staticpages"
    values:
      static: "true"
```

and in your layout file (or page) you filter the posts and loop with:

```
{% assign posts = site.posts | where:"static", "true" %}
{% for post in posts %}...
```

This works very well for me...

Comment: Thanks, but do I still need to respect the post title format when doing it this way? (01-03-2015-title.md) ?

Comment: Thats the thing, i want to be able to loop trough markdown files like you loop trough pages. But then in a subfolder of the posts folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can browse to a folder by setting it in the URL.
If the default URL is:

> http://prose.io/#<account>/<repository>/

Then you can add the branch and folder relative path in the URL:

> http://prose.io/#<account>/<repository>/tree/master/_posts/staticpages